# Push Notification - Model is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, push-notification

following a tutorial written in Typescript I decide to write in JS, but I'm having problems to save subscription.

server.js:

```
app.post("/subscription", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        (async() => {
            const subscription = req.body;
            const newsub = create(subscription);
            console.log(newsub);
        })();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

req.body content:

```
{
  endpoint: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dYGGHvDYLtk:APA91bHIkbLj-Fi0VKrhRuemQZiwc1G49bls0obRGlyPJ6MLisgm3s_lGLvts9jKUaAHKWxxMFlw7imLY8YqEU1C83YNRREdZ70nnVamFFLSANWpZ922z-tysSQhEjBquhISE9rv2RtK',
  expirationTime: null,
  keys: {
    p256dh: 'BOVN3GYiheBK77iPxZecbagZCMXLi06YE8pe-O-dKSmd8r_ccObMYyJ8oYbIQw7htNSxIv4mP5awABRq0LskE6I',
    auth: '8x9bTem324oY4-P9jKcuSQ'
  }
}
```

Model and Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const SubscriptionSchema = new Schema({
    endpoint: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    expirationTime: { type: Number, required: false },
    keys: {
        auth: String,
        p256dh: String,
    },
});
// console.log(`Log Schema: ${SubscriptionSchema}`);

const model = mongoose.model('Subs', SubscriptionSchema);
// console.log(`Log Model: ${model}`);

module.export = { model }
```

Subscription Controller:

```
const { model } = require('./model')

const create = async(subscription) => {
    try {
        const newSubscription = new model(subscription);
        const savedSubscription = await newSubscription.save();
        return savedSubscription.toObject();
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
};

module.exports = { create }
```

After run post request I receive this message:

> TypeError: model is not a constructor
> at create (/home/thiago/Documentos/Coding/push_notification/subscriptionRepository.js:5:33)

Anyone can help to understand what is it?

Comment: show `subscriptionRepository`

Comment: it is Subscription Controller